# Android OnClickListener does not get fired when clicked on first image in the grid

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I have a fragment which has grid view displaying upto 5 images. The OnClickListener does not get fired for first image in the grid but it works when clicked on other images in the grid.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(_activity);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    String imageURLs = _filePaths.get(position).toString();
    Picasso.with(this._activity).load(imageURLs).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(imageView);

    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth,
            imageWidth));

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));

    return imageView;
}

class OnImageClickListener implements OnClickListener {

    int _postion;

    // constructor
    public OnImageClickListener(int position) {
        this._postion = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(_activity, FullScreenViewActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("position", _postion);
        i.putExtra("PATHS", _filePaths);
        _activity.startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this by setting the position as Tag of the `ImageView` in the `getView()` method and getting its Tag(position) in the `onClick()` method.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(_activity);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    String imageURLs = _filePaths.get(position).toString();
    Picasso.with(this._activity).load(imageURLs).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(imageView);

    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth,
            imageWidth));

    imageView.setTag(position);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(this);

    return imageView;
}

  @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(_activity, FullScreenViewActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("position", v.getTag()+"");
    i.putExtra("PATHS", _filePaths);
    _activity.startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Also don't forget to implement the `View.OnClickListener`

Comment: The issue is, onClick does not even get fired when clicked on first image in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by attaching OnItemClick directly to gridView instead of imageView.

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), FullScreenViewActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("position", position);
            i.putExtra("PATHS", imagePaths);
            view.getContext().startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```